# Grails Foreign Key Update - Performance Update Object

Tags: performance, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am creating a lot of objects and I am trying to get a bit of a performance boost.  Currently I have an assignment for a gorm object attribute that I could get better performance out of if I could set the foreign key manually.

For Example

```
def oldBook = Book.findByTitle("Of Mice and Men")
def newBook = new Book()
newBook.author = oldBook.author //This line could be faster
```

The line that could be faster if it didn't have to look up the author object on the oldBook.  Ideally the line would look more like this. (fyi these don't actually work)

```
newBook.authorId = oldBook.authorId
// or
newBook.setAuthorId(oldBook.authorId)
```

Is something like this possible in grails?  Perhaps it's possible but dangerous.  I'm using version grails 2.2.1, Hibernate, and Oracle.  The only other thought I had on this is I could eagerly load the author object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your best bet:

```
newBook.author = Author.load(oldBook.authorId)
```

This takes advantage of the dynamic `fooId` property that doesn't trigger a load of the book's `Author` instance. Using the `load()` method creates a proxy for the `Author` with only the `id` value stored, and as long as only the `id` is accessed, there won't be a database hit to fully load the instance. This basically makes the proxy a wrapper for the FK value.

Comment: Ahhh yes,  very nice.  Thanks so much!